# Query Event : Check whether a particular item present in an object array

Tags: mongodb, titanium, cloud, titanium-mobile

In my application I'm querying to events. I've to select the events that meets the following requirements.

**1. Value of user_id should not be equal to the current user's id**

**2. The custom field 'cancelled' should be false**

**3. The custom field 'participants' should contain current user's id**

*In which `cancelled` property will have a boolean value and `participants` is an array that contains some objects.*

```
participants array:

participants : [{"userID":"52a15bebf172080g3g02abcd","nickname":"Anand"},{"userID":"58t85eryjc2fx3489nx4m90d","nickname":"Midhun"}];
```

I have written the following for getting the events

```
function getUsers(user){
    Cloud.Events.query({
    per_page: 1000,
    where : {
        "cancelled" : false,
        "user_id":{"$ne":user.id},
        //TODO: here I need to get the participants whose userID is equal to user.id
        }
    }, function(e){
        if (e.success) {
            alert('Success:\n' + 'Count: ' + e.events.length);
        } else {
            alert('Error:\n' +
                ((e.error && e.message) || JSON.stringify(e)));
        }
    });
}
```

How can I check whether user.id is present in the participants object array?

**UPDATE**

I tried the following

```
where : {
    "cancelled" : false,
    "participants.userID" : user.id,
    "user_id":{"$ne":user.id},
}
```

but returns 0. It should return 1.

Comment: `participants.userID : user.id`?

Comment: @WiredPrairie: Thank you for your response. I tried that but didn't worked.

Comment: You'll need to add a full document example to your question. In a very simple test, I tested it, and the syntax I suggested worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of research I found the answer. I changed the where clause as follows

```
where : {
    "cancelled" : false,
    "participants" :{ "$elemMatch" : { "userID" : user.id }}
    "user_id":{"$ne":user.id},
}
```

Complete code as follows

```
function getUsers(user){
    Cloud.Events.query({
       per_page: 1000,
       where : {
          "cancelled" : false,
          "participants" :{ "$elemMatch" : { "userID" : user.id }}
          "user_id":{"$ne":user.id},
       }
    }, function(e){
        if (e.success) {
            alert('Success:\n' + 'Count: ' + e.events.length);
        } else {
            alert('Error:\n' +
                ((e.error && e.message) || JSON.stringify(e)));
        }
    });
}
```

[This link](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) helped me to resolve the issue.